# Testing template_name passed into rails mail method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, rspec, actionmailer

I'm specifying a `template_name` when passing the params to `mail` inside a mailer method like :

```
MyMailerClass < ActionMailer::Base
  def my_mailer_method
    mail(subject: 'Mail Subject', template_name: 'ValidTemplate')
  end
end
```

Link to [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#mailer-views) for reference.
The class that get created from the mail() method, Mail::Message has no reference to the template_name passed in.  Is there a good way to write a unit test for this?  I've trying stubbing some of the methods and test on whats being passed in, but no luck so far.

Comment: Is there a specific error message you are seeing? Including that in your question would be helpful.

Comment: So there's no error that's taking place.  I was just wondering if there was a way to ensure the correct template_name is being used when creating the mailer aside from testing the actual contents of the mailer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rspec then you can assert that the class received the `mail` method with certain arguments:

```
# ensure that you stub the method first so you can make assertions on it later
allow(MyMailerClass).to receive(:mail)

MyMailerClass.my_mailer_method

# verify the method was called with the proper arguments
expect(MyMailerClass).to have_received(:mail).with(template_name: "ValidTemplate")
```

Source: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-5/docs/basics/expecting-messages

If you are using a different test framework, then you can achieve the same result with a mocking library such as [Mocha](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha).